# How could I curl for a request with headers in shell scripting

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, cfnetwork

I tried to execute a CURL statement as follows, for which I am getting required response:

```
curl -s -POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://www.dummy.com/projectname/page_relevance' -d '{"query": "q_string", "results": [{"abstract": "abs_string", "title": "title_string"}, "mode": "value", "cache": true, "source": "value"}'
```

But when i tried to pass variable values to parameter "query", the curl statement mentioned below not works and observed some error statement in response:

```
curl -s -POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://www.dummy.com/projectname/page_relevance' -d '{"query": "$query_string", "results": [{"abstract": "abs_string", "title": "title_string"}, "mode": "value", "cache": true, "source": "value"}'
```

## ERROR Statement:

> Not Found [CFN #0005]
>
> ## It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

But am sure that curl request which i constructed second with variable resembles the same curl request which i executed at first. This is tested using echo which replaces $query_string with correct value.

I also tried in another approach, in which i have not used any variables for single parameter, instead i tried as below:

```
a='{"query": "query_value", "results": [{"abstract": "abs_string", "title": "title_string"}, "mode": "value", "cache": true, "source": "value"}'
curl -s -POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://www.dummy.com/projectname/page_relevance' -d $a
```

I also tried to substitute value of a using `${a}`, `"$a"`, `'$a'`

still same error is been observed.

Comment: remove the "-POST" part as a start, it is completely wrong, then add `--libcurl dump.txt` and check exactly what curl sent for your command and it usually gives you a lot of clues

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes `'` (you're using in `-d` argument) preserve the literal value of each character, including the `$` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)), and that's why your variable `query_string` is not being expanded.

Try this:

```
~$ query_string="my query"

~$ echo '$query_string'
$query_string

~$ echo "$query_string"
my query
```

So, you need to use double quotes `"` if you wish your variables to expand to its values.

However, in order to nest double quotes (inside other double quotes), as in you JSON data, you must either:

1. **escape** the inner quotes, like this:

   ```
   ~$ echo "{\"query\": \"$query_string\"}"
   {"query": "my query"}
   ```

   but that gets very ugly, very soon; or
2. **concatenate** strings under alternating single and double quotes, like this:

   ```
   ~$ echo '{"query": "'"$query_string"'"}"'
   {"query": "my query"}"
   ```

   which may be more readable for shorter strings; or
3. use a **here-document**:

   ```
   ~$ read query <<-END
   {"query": "$query_string"}
   END

   ~$ echo "$query"
   {"query": "my query"}
   ```

   [Here-documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) are particularly convenient for longer documents in which you wish for parameter/variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, etc.

In summary, after defining your JSON query with one of the above ways (perhaps via a here-document), you can write your `curl` command like this:

```
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://www.dummy.com/projectname/page_relevance' -d "$query"
```