# cURL throwing globbing error when JSON data in variable contains a space

Tags: json, bash, curl

Using bash v4.3.48(1) on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and bash v3.2.57 on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 I have this code which POSTs JSON data stored in a variable:

```
#1    
JSON_DATA="Test"; \
curl -X POST "https://www.techotaku.com/json.php" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"data":"'$JSON_DATA'"}'
```

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Test
)
```

However, if $JSON_DATA contains a space...

```
#2
JSON_DATA="A Test"; \
curl -X POST "https://www.techotaku.com/json.php" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"data":"'$JSON_DATA'"}'
```

...it throws an error:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 6
```

I thought this might be due to incorrect use of quotes, but if I echo the JSON data...

```
echo '{"data":"'$JSON_DATA'"}'
```

...it appears well-formed:

```
{"data":"A Test"}
```

Also, if I include the JSON data as a string and not a variable, it works.

```
#3
curl -X POST "https://www.techotaku.com/json.php" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"data":"A Test"}'
```

The only way I can get it to work if the variable contains a space is to enclose the JSON data in double-quotes and escape the literal double-quotes in the string:

```
#4    
JSON_DATA="A Test"; \
curl -X POST "https://www.techotaku.com/json.php" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "{\"data\":\"$JSON_DATA\"}"
```

I would have thought that all 4 examples would have worked. So, can anyone throw any light on why only examples 1,3 and 4 work and example 2 doesn't?

Many thanks, Steve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should quote your variables to prevent word splitting by shell. Your second example:

```
'{"data":"'$JSON_DATA'"}'
```

doesn't work because it's being expanded by `bash` to two words:

```
{"data":"A Test"}
```

so `-d` option receives 2 arguments (`{"data":"A` and `Test"}`). If `JSON_DATA` contained globbing metacharacters, those would cause filename expansion.

To fix it, quote it:

```
'{"data":"'"$JSON_DATA"'"}'
```

Note the use of alternating single and double quotes. This will be expanded to a single word:

```
{"data":"A Test"}
```

Here's [a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035918/404556) I wrote some time ago which also mentions another convenient option, the use of a here-document.

Comment: Many thanks @randomir. Those quotes were messing with my head, but it's simple now you've explained it.

Comment: Thanks @randomir, coming from javascript the triple quotes were a bit too much for me ahah