# Nested cURL call

Tags: bash, curl, cron, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I've one cron task to update my DDNS with my current ip address and do it through a cURL call.

The problem is one of the parameters to pass in the call is the CURRENT IP and in order to discover ir i need to do another cURL call.

I would like to know if is possible to nest two cURL calls in one single script in order to make my cron task avoiding extra scripts

example:

to get my current ip I use

```
curl ipinfo.io/ip
```

to update my ddns i need to do:

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/2wertyh/dns_records/23ertghj" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: tomatechines@gmail.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: 123ertgyh" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"type":"A","name":"qwsdfg.com.br","content":"MY-CURRENT-IP","ttl":1800,"proxied":false}'
```

how can i fit this two calls together in order to make my cron task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), like this:

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/2wertyh/dns_records/23ertghj" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: tomatechines@gmail.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: 123ertgyh" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"type":"A","name":"qwsdfg.com.br","content":"'"$(curl ipinfo.io/ip)"'","ttl":1800,"proxied":false}'
```

String argument for `--data` is composed from three concatenated parts, `'beginning'` `"$(curl ...)"` `'ending'` (more details see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035918/404556)).