# bash - assign variable to curl get request

Tags: bash, curl

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
    curl 'https://shoesworkshop.net/libraries/ajax/ajax.invoice.php?act=viewallinvoice&invoiceid="${line}"&sEcho=1&iColumns=8&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=20&bRegex=false&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=true&bSortable_6=true&bSortable_7=true' -H 'Host: shoesworkshop.net'| sed  's/^[^[[]*:/:/'
done < "$1"
```

inside $line there is a value like this

```
AAAAA
SSSSS
DDDDD
```

and i want to pass $line into curl command
can someone help me how?
i tried "'${line}'" and '${line}' and it still not working
i want to make a repeat call using curl get request from the url using variable from $line

Answer (score 2):

For simple URLs, one way is to just use double quotes for the complete URL, including your variable expansion, `${line}`, like this:

```
curl "https://shoe...&invoiceid=${line}&sEcho=1&iCo...table_7=true"
```

(Under single quotes, your shell variable `line` is not expanded.)

If your URL contains shell-special characters like `$`, it's best to combine both single and double quotes (and concatenate several strings, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035918/404556)). For Example:

```
curl 'https://shoe...&invoiceid='"$line"'&sEcho=1&iCo...table_7=true'
#     ^------ fixed part ------^  ^var^  ^------- fixed part ------^
```

However, if your variable contains **characters that have to be URL-encoded** (like space, `&`, `?`, etc.) it's best to **let `curl` handle that** with `--data-urlencode` option. When called with this option, `curl` will default to `POST` method, but you can override this with `-G`, in which case your parameters will be appended to URL query. For example:

```
line="1&2?3 4"
curl "http://httpbin.org/get?x=1&y=2" --data-urlencode z="$line" -G
```

produces the right URL:

```
http://httpbin.org/get?x=1&y=2&z=1%262%3F3%204
```

---

Your script, fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
    curl --data-urlencode invoiceid="$line" -G 'https://shoesworkshop.net/libraries/ajax/ajax.invoice.php?act=viewallinvoice&sEcho=1&iColumns=8&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=20&bRegex=false&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=true&bSortable_6=true&bSortable_7=true' -H 'Host: shoesworkshop.net' | sed 's/^[^[[]*:/:/'
done < "$1"
```

Comment: i tried but it gave me an illegal character found in url error

Comment: If your `line` includes special chars, those have to be encoded. I've added that case to the answer.

Comment: @abdulrahmansafari, have you managed to try the `--data-urlencode` approach? I'm just curious if you managed to make it work.